# Does order of conditions under where clause in a LINQ query matter

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ. Could anyone please clarify whether the order of conditions under where clause in a LINQ query matter.

for eg: Is there any difference w.r.t performance between below two queries

Query-1

```
from prod in Products 
where prod.ExpiryDate == Products.Where(s => s.ID.Equals(CurrObj.Id) && 
      s.Type.Equals(CurrObj.Type)).Max(s => s.ExpiryDate) && 
      prod.ID.Equals(CurrObj.Id) && prod.Type.Equals(CurrObj.Type) 
select new
{
   AmountFrom = prod.AmountFrom,
   AmountTo = prod.AmountTo
}
```

Query-2

```
from prod in Products 
where prod.ID.Equals(CurrObj.Id) && 
      prod.Type.Equals(CurrObj.Type) &&
      prod.ExpiryDate == Products.Where(s => s.ID.Equals(CurrObj.Id) && s.Type.Equals(CurrObj.Type)).Max(s => s.ExpiryDate)
select new
{
    AmountFrom = prod.AmountFrom,
    AmountTo = prod.AmountTo
}
```

**Edit**: I just measured the performance. Query-1 takes around 900ms whereas Query-2 takes 350ms.

Comment: This looks very specific. Consider measuring it yourself.

Comment: LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Objects? Something else? (Also *please* use line breaks to avoid all that scrolling... it's extremely hard to read your code at the moment.)

Comment: Sorry. Its LINQ to Objects. I have reformatted my query.

Comment: I assume that it may be similar to if statement, in second query you compare first ID, if ID is diffrent it will not proceed further checking while in first "where" will force to enumerate through whole collection. Just like in the "if" statement where first condition is false then process of checking is supressed so it will not reach further conditions.

Comment: I just measured the performance. Query-1 takes around 900ms whereas Query-2 takes 350ms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's LINQ-To-Objects it matters.

`Enumerable.Where` is comparable to an `if`clause. So this ...

```
if(expensiveMethodThatReturnsBool() && num1 < num2)
{
    // ...
}
```

... is probably less efficient than:

```
if(num1 < num2 && expensiveMethodThatReturnsBool())
{
    // ...
}
```

because `&&` is a short-circuit operator. The second expression is evaluated only if the first returned `true`. The same applies to `||`, the second is evaluated only if the first returned `false`.

[7.11 Conditional logical operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310(v=vs.71).aspx)

---

It's similar with chained `Where`s. Similar because predicates are applied to every remaining item which passed through the previous `Where`.

So this...

```
.Where(x => expensiveMethodThatReturnsBool(x))
.Where(x => x.num1 < x.num2)
```

can also be less efficient than:

```
.Where(x => x.num1 < x.num2)
.Where(x => expensiveMethodThatReturnsBool(x))
```

The first is logically equivalent to:

```
.Where(x => expensiveMethodThatReturnsBool(x) && x.num1 < x.num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well consider it yes, as all thos generated as SQL at the end the two different sql statements will be different, now in certain situations order of things in sql matter, but you cant tell for sure unless you measure it.

I suggest to noy worry about that until you face or know something for sure upon measuring performance.